# How to format expiry credit card date MM/YYYY

Tags: javascript

I need to format an expiry date for credit card in the following format MM/YYYY using a regex which looks like this `^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/?([0-9]{4})$` but when it comes to add slashes it groups everything in 2. The question here is how do I add slashes only after first 2 instead of each 2?

```
const formatCardDate = (item) => {
  let input = item;

  if (/^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/?([0-9]{4})$/.test(input)) {
    input = input.match(new RegExp(".{1,2}", "g")).join("/");
  }

  return input;
};
```

Comment: Instead of trying to find the perfect pattern, validate it as a date. Expiration of 04/9999 is probably wrong.

Comment: I am not trying to validate as a valid date. I am trying to add the slash while user is making the input. I can simply add the slash at the end once the length is equal with 6 but that's not my point here

Comment: This is not as easy as it seems to be done right. Have you considered using a library for expiration input?

Comment: No because I want to understand the concept instead of using a library. There are many ways to build this part even with dropdown for month and year. But as I have already done something for full date DD/MM/YYYY I would like to see something like this for MM/YYYY

Comment: Can you provide a couple of examples of input/expected-output pairs? it's unclear how much of that function is incorrect.

Comment: I want to input 122023 and return 12/2023 as now its returning 12/20/23

Comment: The reason why it's not so simple is because you can paste values.

Comment: @CallumMorrisson the value I have to input is `122023` and it will add automatically `/` so the return should be `12/2023`. Now what is doing it will add two slashes and the return will be `12/20/23`